# How can I get full color using a decal tool on "Decal-able" items?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've seen some player's inventories, in which their [Flair](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Flair!) has a full set of colors, allowing them to put a lot of cool images on them (like Pokeballs).  I'm trying to do this with a decal tool, but it's only letting me put so many colors on, namely, orange, yellow, and brown.

I want to get bolder and brighter colors into my Flair; how can I get these colors in? This could pertain to items such as Clan Pride, The Conscientious Objector, and the Photo Badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a feature being removed from the [Decal Tool](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Decal_Tool) in the [17/10/11 patch](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/October_17,_2011_Patch):

> It is worth noting that with the removal of the Painterly effect you can no longer create full colored decals and are instead limited to a maximum of five or so colors. Items that had a decal applied before the painterly effect was removed still retain their original color.

The full-colour ones you see must have been decaled before the full-colour feature was removed. However, there remains a way to do it manually, shown by [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaDdnFS3OOI). It involves downloading a folder with two files in it (one for Flair, the other for...I guess the sign); according to the description said files are available [here](http://adf.ly/QgVaX) or [here](http://adf.ly/QgVgb) and apparently designed for some form of Photoshop (the GIMP is probably capable of dealing with it). Edit the template files (you may have to save as new and then overwrite) and use them as your decal.